# Primefaces DataTable doesn't update the display value with a drop box, if the value attribute of <p:selectOneMenu> and <h:outputText> is different

Tags: jsf, primefaces, selectonemenu

I have a dataTable using Primefaces 3.5 as shown [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjjhO.png).

[image]

Now I'm editing the second row with the id 43 as shown in the following [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bE21D.png).

[image]

When I click the tick (the right most column), the row is edited as can be seen in the following [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S5SjO.png).

[image]

It can easily noticed that the name of the state is changed from `xxxx` to `zzz` but the country appears to remain the same which is expected to be updated to `America` from `Germany`.

Actually, the changes have been made to the database but they don't seem to be reflected to the dataTable on completion of the `rowEdit` event.

To observe the change made to the country, the page is required to be reload. Only when this page is reloaded, it displays the correct data as shown [below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLrzr.png).

[image]

---

This is the column in which the country drop box is listed.

```
<p:ajax event="rowEdit" listener="#{stateManagedBean.onRowEdit}" update=":form:dataTable :form:systemMessages :form:messages" process=":form:dataTable :form:systemMessages :form:messages"/>
<p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" listener="#{stateManagedBean.onRowEditCancel}" update=":form:systemMessages :form:messages" process=":form:systemMessages :form:messages"/>


<p:column headerText="Country" sortBy="#{state.country.countryName}" filterBy="#{state.country.countryName}" filterMaxLength="45">                    
    <p:cellEditor>
        <f:facet name="output">
            <h:outputText value="#{state.country.countryName}" />
        </f:facet>
        <f:facet name="input">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" value="#{state.country.countryId}" rendered="true" editable="false" converter="#{longConverter}" converterMessage="The supplied value is incorrect." required="true" requiredMessage="Select an appropriate option." style="width:100%;">
                <f:selectItems var="country" value="#{stateManagedBean.countries}"  itemLabel="${country.countryName}" itemValue="${country.countryId}" itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </f:facet>
    </p:cellEditor>
</p:column>
```

And the following is the `onRowEdit()` method (in JSF managed bean) which is triggered when the tick is clicked.

```
public void onRowEdit(RowEditEvent event)
{
    StateTable stateTable=(StateTable) event.getObject();

    if(stateService.update(stateTable))
    {
        FacesMessage message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Success : ",  "The row with the id "+stateTable.getStateId()+" has been updated successfully.");
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
    }
}
```

The full code of [JSF managed bean](http://pastebin.com/GRV8evZE) and [JSF page](http://pastebin.com/SLJS1Pds).

---

In the `rowEdit()` method (as above), `stateTable.getCountry().getCountryId()` displays the updated `countryId` but using this country object to refer to the corresponding country name  like `stateTable.getCountry().getCountryName()` just displays the old country name (not the updated one). What is the way to get around this?

---

**Important:**

In the XHTML code snippet above, the value attribute of both,

```
<h:outputText value="#{state.country.countryName}"/>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^_^^^^^^^^^^^
<p:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" value="#{state.country.countryId}" .../>
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^_^^^^^^^^^
```

is different which is essential to display country names instead of displaying country ids and referring to the corresponding country ids.

If they are changed to reflect the same `value` attribute,

```
<h:outputText value="#{state.country.countryId}"/>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^_^^^^^^^^^
<p:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" value="#{state.country.countryId}" .../>
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^_^^^^^^^^^
```

then it works as expected (Primefaces showcase example(s) demonstrate(s) just like this).

---

It is the same as updating a footer value dynamically showing the total of numeric values of a column. The footer is not updated while updating a row in that column. The issue has been reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1558).

Comment: Try to follow this example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableRowEditing.jsf and see what is missing.

Comment: In that showcase example, the value of `<h:outputText>` and `<h:selectOneMenu>` is the same which is `value="#{car.color}"`. Doing so, also works in my case (I always look into showcase examples before I can start with them). In my case, however the value of both `<h:outputText>` and `<p:selectOneMenu>` is different which is `value="#{state.countryId.countryName}"` and `value="#{state.countryId.countryId}"` respectively. This doesn't work as expected.

Comment: put it on a form then update the form if the change event is executed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that you are not changing the whole country object. Because you use `#{state.country.countryId}` as value of the `p:selectOneMenu` just the property `countryId` of the currently selected country is changing, but **not** the country, i.e. other properties like `countryName` will remain.

You have to change the value of `p:selectOneMenu` to `#{state.country}` and the `itemValue` of `f:selectItems` to `#{country}`. Look at the [showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/selectOneMenu.jsf) for `p:selectOneMenu`.

Additionally, as `country` is a POJO for which no converter is available by default, you will have to implement a `countryConverter` and use it for the conversion when selecting an item via `p:selectOneMenu`.

Use the following code for the `p:selectOneMenu` and the this [article](http://balusc.blogspot.co.at/2007/09/objects-in-hselectonemenu.html) as support for implementing the converter.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="cmbCountryMenu" value="#{state.country}" rendered="true" editable="false" converter="#{countryConverter}" converterMessage="The supplied value is incorrect." required="true" requiredMessage="Select an appropriate option." style="width:100%;">
    <f:selectItems var="country" value="#{stateManagedBean.countries}"  itemLabel="#{country.countryName}" itemValue="#{country}" itemLabelEscaped="true" rendered="true"/>
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer but sorry, I'm having the same problem with these changes. Additionally, the blog of BalusC is great but it uses `List<javax.faces.model.SelectItem>` which is by the way, an old JSF 1.x thing.

Comment: There is no change in the behavior? Could you post the code of the converter you created? Oh sorry I did not see that.

Comment: Ah! This worked for me. Now I found it quite simple but only after I have implemented. Thank you.